# Add citation/cross-reference directly to equation number

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, citing, equation-number

I am working on a document that references equations in multiple textbooks. To enable the reader to quickly jump to the *exact* location in each source, I would like to add the reference to the equation number like so:

A = B + C (1, cf. [1] (1.123))

Where equation 1 (A = B + C) is adapted from equation (1.123) in source [1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new tag form using `mathtools`' commands. Here, I defined a command `\tagcite` that you can call right before an equation where you need to add a reference. It takes two arguments: the citation label and the equation number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{tagcite}{(}{)}
\newcommand*{\tagcite}[2]{%
    \renewtagform{tagcite}{(}{, cf.\@ \cite{#1} (#2))}
    \usetagform{tagcite}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{equation}{\usetagform{default}}
\begin{document}
\tagcite{ref}{1.123}
\begin{equation}
\label{equation}
A + B = C
\end{equation}
Reference to equation \eqref{equation}.
\tagcite{otherref}{2.345}
\begin{equation}
D + E = F
\end{equation}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
    \bibitem{ref} Source
    \bibitem{otherref} Other source
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Note that I added the line

```
\AfterEndEnvironment{equation}{\usetagform{default}}
```

to reset the tag form to the default after every `equation` environment so that you don't need to reset it manually after using `\tagcite`, but it also has the effect that if you use other tag forms in your document they will constantly be reset. If you intend to use other tag forms you might want to remove this line and reset the tag form manually when necessary.