# How to add custom equation numbers and text in `align` environment?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, labels

I would like to add a custom string just before the equation number in an align environment. In addition, I would like to add some information to the equation number itself (eg. a specific reference for the equation). I was able to produce the following snippet from two other StackExchange threads:

```latex
% Add additional information to equation, including a custom name and the specific location in a reference. Instead of:
% "a²+b²=c² (1)"
% this renders:
% "a²+b²=c² Pythagorean Theorem (1, cf. eq. 1.123 in [1])"
% Syntax:
% \eqlabel{custom string}{bibtex reference}{location in reference}
% eg.:
% \eqlabel{Pythagorean Theorem}{2010_pythagoras_equations}{eq. 1.123}
% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668944
% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/691267
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{eqlabel}{#1 (}{)}
\newcommand*{\eqlabel}[3]{%
    \renewtagform{eqlabel}{#1 (}{, cf.\@ #3 in \cite{#2})}
    \usetagform{eqlabel}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{equation}{\usetagform{default}}
```

This works reasonably well for equations (although the equation is no longer centered on the page, but rather on the remaining free space in the line):

```latex
\begin{equation}
    \vec{s} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\vec{f} \eqlabel{Solution to the Inventory Problem}{heijungs_computational_2002}{eq. 2.21}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

How can I:

1. make this work in the `align` environment (for each line)
2. make sure the equation is centered on the page, not on the remaining free space in the line

?

Comment: For centering, perhaps forgetting `eqlabel` and usimg `\tag` or adding something like `\hfill\mathllap{\text{....}}` would help, with 1 or 2 `&` before it, depending on the context and what you really want to achieve. But the result will be very weird if the text `...` or the equation is are too long.